# React router Link is changing the url but not actually redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router. And it's working fine, But If I just change the :id in url, it doesn't redirect the page

```
 <Route path="/school/:id" component={School}/>
```

e-g: If am already at school page with url "school/234" and I click on another link with url "school/908". It doesn't work. Url does change but content doesn't

Comment: Please follow this link I hope it's helpful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235339/after-page-refresh-react-page-not-working/56235596#56235596
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can basically try this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.postId !== prevProps.match.params.postId) {
      discussionId = this.props.match.params.postId;
      this.props.getSomeData(discussionId);
    }
  }
```